# HTML5 Audio - Why not working on iOS? (NO autoplay involved)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, html5-audio

I built a simple demo app to test HTML5-Audio. When you touch or click the robot's head the webapp *says* "eins", which is german for "one" (I had this soundfile on my computer for testing).

**You can test the demo app here: http://jstesproject.cwsurf.de/**

*(Remarks: The robot is the phonegap icon, but there is NO phonegap or cordova technology involved. It is plain HTML5, Javascript (+jQuery) and CSS. Also, you have manually click the robot's head, so there is NO autostart involved.)*

The webapp works fine on desktop browsers (I tested Chrome and Firefox) and on Android native browser (I tested with Android 4.0). However, I cannot get it to work under iOS (iPhone, neither Chrome nor Safari). The Audio-Object throws an error (code 4).

**Why is this? How can I get it to work under iOS?** There is no autostart involved. Please see my code below:

**Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  clearLog();

  log('Document ready!');

  $('.clickable').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).html();

    playAudio('res/audio/', '1.wav');
  });
});

//==============
// AUDIO
function playAudio(path, src) {
  log('playAudio called! Arguments: ' + path + ', ' + src);

  $('#path').html('path -> ' + path);
  $('#file').html('file -> ' + path + src);

  if (typeof Audio != "undefined") {
    log('Playing Audio using HTML5...');

    var audioUrl = path + src;
    log('audioUrl: ' + audioUrl);

    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = audioUrl;
    audio.type = 'audio/x-wav';

    audio.addEventListener('error', function() {
      log('Audio error: ' + audioUrl + '; ' + JSON.stringify(audio.error));
      $('#audioStatus').html('Audio error: ' + audioUrl + '; ' + JSON.stringify(audio.error));
    });

    audio.addEventListener('play', function() {
      log('Starting audio: ' + audioUrl + '; MIME-type: ' + audio.type);
      $('#audioStatus').html('Playing audio: ' + audioUrl);
    });

    audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      log('Playback ended: ' + audioUrl);
      $('#audioStatus').html('Stopped...');
    });

    audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
      audio.play();
    });
  } else {
    log('Cannot play audio via HTML5 -> !(typeof Audio != "undefined")');
  }
}

//==============
// UTILS
function log(s, showAlert) {
  var now = new Date();
  var text = makeTwoDigits(now.getHours()) + ':' + makeTwoDigits(now.getMinutes()) + ':' + makeTwoDigits(now.getSeconds()) + ' >> ' + s;

  $('#console').append('<p>' + text + '</p>');
  console.log(text);

  if (showAlert) {
    alert(text);
  }
}

function clearLog() {
  $('#console').html('<p><strong>Console</strong> <span>[clear]</span></p>');

  $('#console span').click(function() {
    clearLog();
  });
}

function makeTwoDigits(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    return '0' + x;
  } else {
    return '' + x;
  }
}
```

```css
 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   background-color: #EEE;
 }
 .clickable {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .icon {
   text-align: center;
 }
 .app {
   width: 256px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 50px auto;
   padding: 20px;
   background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #8bceec);
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .numbers,
 .display {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .app .numbers span {
   float: left;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   line-height: 32px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .app .display span {
   float: left;
   width: 190px;
   height: 50px;
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   line-height: 32px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .app .debug {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
 #console {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 20px auto;
   padding: 20px;
   background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #00d3ec);
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 #console p {
   margin: 10px 0px;
 }
 #console span {
   float: right;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
  <title>I can say one!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="clickable icon">CLICK MY ROBOT-HEAD!</div>
    <div class="clickable icon">
      <img src="icon.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="debug">Info:</div>
    <div id="path" class="debug">N/A</div>
    <div id="file" class="debug">N/A</div>
    <div id="audioStatus" class="debug">N/A</div>
  </div>

  <div id="console">
    <p><strong>Console</strong>  <span>[clear]</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as far as I played around with html5 audio I had issues with iOS as well - it has lots of limitations; even with dedicated sound libraries there are limits on iOS - sometimes you cant change volume, other times you cant pause audio while playing etc. For my case I got it to work (but was using Cordova & Phonegap Build) with one of the libraries after all. Don't forget to check the codec (ogg/mp3...). Check this for more info http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the call to `audio.play()` outside the "canplay" event listener. To play audio/video on mobile devices you need direct, physical and **synchronous** interaction from the user. You nailed the first two, but when you put that `audio.play()` inside the event listener you break the synchronous requirement.

```
// BEFORE
audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    audio.play();
});

// AFTER
audio.play();
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a life saver!!! Thank you so much, it works. Also, great explanation why it does!