# Background audio on a website working on laptops automatically but not working on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, audio, jquery-mobile

I have a website which has background music playing when you visit the website in laptop or desktop but the music doesn't work in mobile browsers.

The code I am using to have background music is

```
<audio loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="Ada/Song.mp3"" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

I don't want on-click audio and looking just for auto play on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. Mobile browsers are designed not to play audio or video unless the user performs an action on the page itself. What you want is therefore impossible unless you find a bug in the browser which you can exploit.

See, for example, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023211/html5-audio-why-not-working-on-ios-no-autoplay-involved).