# HTML 5 Audio Not Working On IPhone Or Andriod

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I've made a video game in JS that works perfectly when run on a desktop browser.  On mobile browsers, the sound doesn't work.  Some research pointed out that `sound.play()` is disabled on most mobile browsers and you can only get the sound to work if you put it in an event handler.  That is precisely what I've done and it still doesn't work.  Here are the relevant sections of the code.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks!

```
function eventTouchStart(event) {
    touchobj = event.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point      
        startX = touchobj.clientX; // get x coord of touch point
        mouseX = touchobj.clientX;
        explode.play();

}

function init_app() {
    var explodeSound ;
    explodeSound = document.createElement("audio");
    document.body.appendChild(explodeSound);
    audioType = supportedAudioFormat(explodeSound);
    explodeSound.setAttribute("src", "explode1." + 
    audioType);
explodeSound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", itemLoaded, false);
}
```

```
theCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", eventTouchStart, false);
```

Comment: `supportedAudioFormat` in undefined. Nothing is being called, as far as I can see.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25025149/2740650

Comment: supporedAudioFormat is defined elsewhere in the code.  I've only included the code relevant to this question.

Comment: It turns out the problem isn't the mobile aspect.  The problem is Safari.  The sound works on mobile and desktop if you are using Chrome.  I've made sure I have OGG, WAV and MP3 versions of the audio files and that got the sound to work on both desktop and mobile as long as you are not using Safari.  I have to figure out why the sound doesn't work on Safari now.

Comment: All fixed.  I don't know what I did, but it started working on both mobile and desktop Safari now.  Thanks for the suggestions everyone.  I think making the code select the audio file type depending on browser fixed it.