# HTML5 audio on android chrome, not playing unless an alert() is called

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I've searched other questions and it seems like this is a problematic area. Unfortunately no one else seemed to have the same issue as me.

I'm essentially trying to trigger an mp3 when a button is clicked. I'm having no problem with desktop browsers but when I try on android I get nothing. I added an `alert()` just to check that the onclick function was firing and to my surprise after dismissing it the audio plays.

I'm aware that user interaction is required in order to trigger audio but I thought an onclick event would suffice. Is there another gotcha that I am missing?

I've included two snippets to display the difference.

**This version works on desktop but not android**

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
let audio = new Audio('https://archive.org/download/BirdCall/chrysococcyx-basalis.mp3')

const handleClick = (file) => {
  if (file.paused) {
    file.play();
  } else {
    file.currentTime = 0;
  }
}


btn.onclick = () => handleClick(audio)
```

```html
<h1>Working On Desktop</h1>

<button>Bird Call</button>
```

**This version works on android**

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
let audio = new Audio('https://archive.org/download/BirdCall/chrysococcyx-basalis.mp3')

const handleClick = (file) => {
  alert('Audio will play.')
  if (file.paused) {
    file.play();
  } else {
    file.currentTime = 0;
  }
}


btn.onclick = () => handleClick(audio)
```

```html
<h1>Working On Android Chrome</h1>
<button>Bird Call</button>
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i have come across a post which could help you to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023211/html5-audio-why-not-working-on-ios-no-autoplay-involved

Comment: @AqibNaeem Thank you for the suggestion but the issue they had was trying to play from callback that was not user triggered.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange problem.  I tried it on an old android phone and couldn't reproduce the issue (the audio plays without any need for an alert box).  I can't see any obvious explanation, but perhaps chrome is waiting for user input before loading the audio file, your device is failing to start loading it quickly enough, then it's hitting a timeout.  The alert box might just introduce enough delay.  It's a long shot, but you could try adding an extra interaction for the user to load the audio first, like this:

```js
let load = document.querySelector("#load");
let play = document.querySelector("#play");

// different audio file used in this snippet, because archive.org is
// blocked by my ISP ... damn internet censorship 
let audio = new Audio("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3");

play.onclick = () => { audio.play(); }
load.onclick = () => { audio.load(); }

audio.oncanplay = () => {
  load.disabled = true;
  play.disabled = false;
};
```

```html
<button id="play" disabled>Play</button>
<button id="load">Load</button>
```